# How to execute an ajax call just after a request to download a file in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, download, actionresult

what I want to do is to update the number of "new files" after I read one. First of all, I have a text with the quantity of files that are new (by new files I mean the ones that I havent downloaded or clicked to download yet).

```
<a id="Plans">Plans (@Model.NewPlansQuantity)</a>
```

whenever I click in the "download link" I must download the file and update the number of files that I considered new. This is the download link:

```
foreach (var item in @Model.MediaItems)
        {
        <tr>
            <td> 
                @Html.ActionLink(@item.Name, "DownloadFile", "Controller",
                                 new
                                    {
                                        FileName = item.FileName,
                                        Type = item.Type,
                                        FileID = item.MediaItemID
                                    }, new { @class = "DownloadLink" })
            </td>
```

This link calls the following action:

```
public FilePathResult DownloadFile(string FileName, int Type, int FileID)
    {
        var file= FileRepository.GetFiles(FileID);
        var fileroute = FilesRepository.FileRoute.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == Type);

        if (file != null)
        { 
            file.Read = true;
            FileRepository.SaveFile(file );
        }

        var route = Server.MapPath(Url.Content(fileroute.Route));

        var path = Path.Combine(route, FileName);

        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(path);

        if (info.Exists)
        {
            return File(path, "application/octet-stream", FileName);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, "Not found");
        } 
    }
```

What I'm doing in the action method is to update the File Entity as Read and the Download it. After doing that I must update the text of the amount of new files, which is the first line of code above (by doing an ajax call I think).  I tried doing the ajax call in the following event:

```
    $('.DownloadLink').live("click", function () {

       //Tried to do the ajax call here
    });
```

I tried to do the ajax call in the download link event click but that didnt work. It seemed that the ajax call was being stopped maybe because I was doing the request to download the file at the same time. Does anyone knows any way to do this?

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have updated the question, let me know if it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I didn't explain my problem clearly, anyway I found the answer of what I was looking for in this post.

[Using ASP.NET MVC, can I download a file using a jQuery GET and FilePathResult?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884655/using-asp-net-mvc-can-i-download-a-file-using-a-jquery-get-and-filepathresult)